# Why does Windows 7 make me click a button when I turn it on?

Tags: windows-7, login, administrator, login-screen

I have removed the password for my admin account on Windows 7. Now when I turn the machine on, I have to click a button with my name underneath it — representing the admin account — to log in. Why is this? I want Windows to go all the way when I turn it on, not stop at the login screen. That's why I removed the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the password is not enough (as you have discovered). I hope you realize that it is a Bad Idea to have an account without a password, but to answer your question:

> 1. Click Start, type netplwiz, and then press Enter.
> 2. In the User Accounts dialog box, click the account you want to automatically log on to.If it is available, clear the Users Must Enter A User Name And Password To Use This Computer check box.
> 3. Click OK.
> 4. In the Automatically Log On dialog box, enter the user’s password twice and click OK.

Instructions from: [Configure a User Account to Log On Automatically on Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx).

Comment: And it's an _especially_ bad idea to do this with an admin account.

Answer (score 1):

Open a Run command and type in the following

control userpasswords2

Untick the box at the top "users must enter a user name and passowrd to use this computer"

Hit OK

.
[image]